# I've heard that there's a GR"A that says there is no need for hishtadlus for shidduchim. Has anyone come across this?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shidduchim-dating, vilna-gaon

I heard that it was in his sefer Hadras Kodesh, on the pasuk in Tehillim אם ה׳ לא יבנה בית

I can't find the sefer. Does anyone have a copy or an online source where I can see this?

Comment: This might be interesting: |(not an answer) "Some people, especially yeshiva buchrim do not approach shadchanim, but rather wait to hear a suggestion. They feel that trying contradicts their bitachon. Some specifically quote the Gra who says that the efforts people make to find a zivug is in vain, because everything is from Hashem. However R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach corrects this misinterpretation of the Gra and states : “Even though Hashem makes shidduchim, one must still do hishtadlus, though less than one would do for one’s other needs.” -https://yismach.com/HilchosShidduchimBooklet.pdf

Comment: The link in that article leads to this sefer that brings the source https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47487&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=

Comment: Cf. *B'reishis Rabba* ([68:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.68.4?lang=bi)): "יֵשׁ שֶׁהוּא הוֹלֵךְ אֵצֶל זִוּוגוֹ וְיֵשׁ שֶׁזִּוּוּגוֹ בָּא אֶצְלוֹ, יִצְחָק בָּא זִוּוּגוֹ אֶצְלוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (בראשית כד, סג): וַיֵּצֵא יִצְחָק לָשׂוּחַ בַּשָּׂדֶה, יַעֲקֹב הָלַךְ אֵצֶל זִוּוּגוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיֵּצֵא יַעֲקֹב מִבְּאֵר שָׁבַע." Note, however, that even Yitzchak's case involved some measure of *hishtadlus* (aside from Eli'ezer's efforts); both Ya'akov and Yitzchak had to "go out" before encountering their match (ויצא יצחק, ויצא יעקב).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[יהל אור: פרשת פקודי היכל ו, דף ל"ג טור ב](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38078&st=&pgnum=125)**

H/T @Shmuel and @Chatzkel who cited the analysis in [שמחה לאי''ש](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47487&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=) which brings down the source.

Comment: I see the source in the gemara, but I don't see there where it says that hishtadlus is not necessary. Am I missing it?

Comment: Most of the first half of column 2 concerns this topic... most explicitly line 13/14 of column 2 states: ששוא הוא עסק בני אדם בענין הזיווג שהכל הוא מאת השם - that the involvement of man in the realm of 'pairs' (זיווג) is in vain for everything comes from God.