# Does everyone end up with their 'soulmate'/bashert?

Tags: marriage, divorce, soul, zivug

I ask this in all respect because there are people who end up not having a romantic partner or spouse in their life. Yet, there is an assertion that HaShem has designated for each individual a soulmate. Does any rabbinic source have an explanation for this phenomenon? (Please cite quotations, if any, thanks in advance).

Comment: How do you reconcile בזעת אפיך תאכל לחם with gluten sensitivity? It's not a universal guarantee, just a general observation.

Comment: I think you're getting Bereishis 2:24 wrong. It's not a promise, it's a commandment (of sorts).

Comment: @ElonMusk can you elaborate on how Bereishis 2:24 is a commandment of sorts? thanks

Comment: Rashi says it's an injunction against forbidden relations.

Comment: @shmosel That's right. But isn't it so that HaShem has designated for each person a bashert? (I hear this commonly assured by rabbis.)

Comment: @ddas91600 Artscroll translates that posuk as follows: "For this reason, a man SHALL leave his father and his mother and cling to his wife and they shall become one flesh."

Comment: @ElonMusk That is the case. Yet, I've heard from a number of rabbis that HaShem has designated for each individual a bashert...Do you know of any source explaining as to why someone may not have a bashert?

Comment: The concept definitely exists. The gemara says before a person is born it's declared in heaven who he will marry. If you're asking about that in general, maybe clarify the question.

Comment: @shmosel Fixed. Operating from this information, then, why is it that some people end up not having, at the very least, a partner?

Comment: Then again, it's also decreed which house and field you will have. But not everyone gets a field in life.

Comment: @shmosel Am I to take it that some people are born without a designated bashert? is there a source affirming this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use free will to avoid getting married?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131154/is-it-possible-to-use-free-will-to-avoid-getting-married)

Comment: In Breslev tradition whoever you marry is by definition your Ziwwug. But it may not be the Ziwwug ha'Amiti. There are eight Ziwwugim and depending on the man's Avoda he attains which one. That's the Ari I believe but I can't cite maybe someone can.

Comment: By saying Hallel and hodaah enthusiastically to H"Y and by learning Halakhot,  you will find your Ziwwug ha'Amiti -- L. Etzot, Chitting, from L. Moharan II:2. And also by saying Nanach in simple faith -- Saba

Comment: Typo Chittun חיתון

Answer (score 4):

We do say that Hashem finds a match for everyone, as in Maseches Sotah 2A. Skip the next paragraph if you already know that Gemarah.

---

Here's a simple summary of the relevant part of that Gemarah. There appears to be an argument between Reish Lakish and R' Yochanan regarding whether a person finds a match depending on their merits. In support of R' Yochanan's view that it is independent of one's actions, the Gemarah quotes Rav saying that three things are determined for a person 40 days before their fetal conception, and one of those things is בת פלוני לפלוני, apparently deciding their match. The Gemarah concludes that in reality there never was an argument, but rather one's first match is predetermined while the second is dependent on one's actions.

---

The interpretation of the Meiri on this section answers your question, I believe. I'll paraphrase the relevant section in English. I got it from [alhatorah.org](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Sotah/2a.8#e0n6), and I suggest reading it in his words (if you use the link I posted it will be in the sixth paragraph).

---

---

When the Gemarah differentiates between the first and second matches, saying that the first is predetermined, it does not mean one's first *spouse* is predetermined, and that if he (for example) divorces her, his chance of finding a second wife is dependent on his actions. Instead, the first **proclamation** is predetermined, while the second is dependent on one's actions. Why? *Because the principle that it depends on one's actions is always true, just that before one's conception, one is deemed a tzaddik, having never sinned, and therefore they are automatically found righteous and deserving.*

It follows from this reading that even finding one's first basheret can be diverted, G-d forbid. Further, the Meiri clarifies that when it says "the match depends on one's actions", that does not only mean *finding the match*, but also which type of person is found. Positive traits will engender the merit/ability to find a match in someone with similar positive traits.

So basically, if you remain a tzaddik then yes, it's predetermined, but otherwise there can be obstructions (G-d forbid) or diversions to people of variable quality.

---

---

Note that there are other interpretations.

Comment: I've fixed my question. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: But then how do you explain bad people who have a soulmate?

Comment: @Miguel if by soulmate, you mean someone that fits their distasteful character traits and encourage them, then it makes perfect sense, based on the idea in the second to last paragraph, that traits engender like traits.